# My Mac would turn on but it would get stuck on the white screen upon startup after chime

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

My Mac turns on but it gets stuck on the white screen upon startup after the chime. I have OS X 10.7.5

I have tried many things unsuccessfully like:

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>: Boot to OS X Recovery Mode => The window does not pop out.

<kbd>Option</kbd>: Access Mac Startup Manager => When I choose the Recovery disk, again it goes to white screen.

<kbd>Option</kbd>: Access Mac Startup Manager => Again it goes to white screen.

I reset <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>: Reset PRAM => with no luck

I reset SMC, disconnected the battery cable and held the button for 5 seconds => No luck

Used <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>: Single User Mode => Type `fsck –fy` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>

I typed  `/sbin/mount -uw /`:

```
hfs: Removed 2 orphaned  / unlined files and 0 directories
```

I tried:

```
touch /private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
exit
```

=> This didn't work either

When I connected in Target Mode T via Thunderbolt cable to another Mac => I was able to scan entire disk drive and fixed any errors on disk => but now still unsuccessful with boot up.

When I was in Verbose Mode I noticed the following line:

```
SMC: :smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode

BootCacheControl: Unable to open /var/db/BootCaches.playlist: 2 no such file or directory
```

Do you have any recommendations what I should try next?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, it looks like you did almost everything already. What I have left for you are reinstalling your OS X and Reset PRAM.

Comment: Yes I did PRAM => command-option-p-r with no luck either :(

Comment: How would I reinstall OS X since when I am in Alt/Option    Access Mac Startup Manager =>  My window gets stuck on the white screen and does not move ? Do you think would it be good to format drive through Target Disk Mode and then to try install using USB Stick with installation files ?  Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hold Command + Option + R during boot.
It will go to Internet Recovery mode, it will download original Mac OS X that came with your Macbook and allows you to remove your partitions using Disk Utility and install a new Mac OS X on it.